# Maya 3D import to OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I have created a object using autodesk maya 3D, may I ask whether the object can import to openGL ES or not? thanks a lot.

**Edit**

I have found the solution that we can save our maya file as .obj file to be import in openGL ES in Xcode.

Comment: or u all got any other way to draw 3D object in openGL ES ?..i got a template but very hard to understand the code in open GL ES...

Comment: Another way? There is only one way of drawing in GL ES, and that's using vertex arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/